# pybluezについて

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluez

Raspberry 3 model Bを使って複数の端末のbleのscanをしたいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。
Pythonは2.7.9、bluezは5.19で、下記のURLのコードを使用しています。
https://github.com/switchdoclabs/iBeacon-Scanner-/blob/master/testblescan.py
エラー文は:

```
pi@raspberry: ~/iBeacon-Scanner- $ sudo python testblescan.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "testblescan.py", line 4. in <module>
  import blescan
 File "/home/pi/iBeacon-Scanner-/blescan.py" , line 21, In <module>
  import bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez 
ImportErrot: No module named bluetooth._bluetooth
```

エラー内容を調べたところpybluezが入っていないとのことなので、下記を実行しましたが

```
pi@raspberry: ~ $ pip install pybluez
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pybluez in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
cleaning up...
```

と表示されます。

raspberry piやpythonを初めて触るので修正方法がわからず困っています。
解決方法を教えていただけると助かります。

また、pythonのバージョンが悪いと考え  python3.4.2で環境設定し実行したところ

```
 pi@raspberry: ~/iBeacon-Scanner- $ sudo python3 testblescan.py
  File "testblescan.py", line 16
   sys.exit(1)
             ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

とエラーが表示されてしまいました。
pythonの知識がなく修正方法がわからないです。

どちらのバージョンでもいいのでご教授いただけると助かります。

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> ImportErrot: No module named bluetooth._bluetooth
> ```

複数のpythonがインストールされていて`python`と`pip`が違うバージョンになっているのではないでしょうか。

`which python pip`で確認してみてください。

> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

[Google翻訳](https://translate.google.com/?hl=ja#en/ja/inconsistent%20use%20of%20tabs%20and%20spaces%20in%20indentation)によると、「インデントでのタブとスペースの一貫性のない使用」だそうです。

Pythonでは[for文やif文のブロックをインデントで解釈するので](http://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming)、他の言語より厳密になっています。
Python3ではインデントでタブとスペースを混合してはいけないで、どちらかに統一して下さい。(スペースを推奨します）

タブはエディタによって4幅だったり8幅だったりしてソースが見づらくなる可能性があるので、Pythonに限らずタブとスペースの混合は止めたほうがいいです。